# Stored procedure (SQL Server), can't find the issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This stored procedure is use for searching records.

When I only fill in the parameter `@ID` or `@FirstName`, it works. But not if I only fill in `@LastName`.

**For example:**

- `@ID = 1`, the rest is `NULL` --> should give 1 row --> RESULT: 1 row (ok)
- `@ID = NULL, @FirstName = 'Tim'`, the rest is `NULL` --> should give 1 row --> RESULT: 1 row (ok)
- `@ID = NULL, @FirstName = NULL, @LastName = 'BlaBla'`, the rest is `NULL` 
  --> should give 1 row --> RESULT: all rows (Not OK)

Anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE lookupSubscriber 
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @ID int,
  @firstname nvarchar(50), 
  @lastname nvarchar(60),
  @street nvarchar(80),
  @housenumber nvarchar(6),
  @companyname nvarchar(50),
  @city nvarchar(50),
  @ResultString nvarchar(80) OUTPUT,
  @ResultValue int OUTPUT,
  @ResultCount int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Replacing empty strings with NULL
IF @ID = 0 BEGIN SET @ID = NULL; END
IF @firstname = '' BEGIN SET @firstname = NULL; END
IF @lastname = '' BEGIN SET @lastname = NULL; END
IF @street = '' BEGIN SET @street = NULL; END
IF @companyname = '' BEGIN SET @companyname = NULL; END
IF @housenumber = '' BEGIN SET @housenumber = NULL; END
IF @city = '' BEGIN SET @city = NULL; END

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT s.ID, COALESCE(d.FirstName,'NONE'), COALESCE(d.LastName,'NONE'), d.Street, COALESCE(d.CompanyName,'NONE'), d.HouseNumber, c.name
    FROM Subscriber s
    INNER JOIN SubscriberDetail d ON d.ID = s.Detail_ID
    INNER JOIN City c ON d.City_ID = c.ID
    WHERE (s.ID = COALESCE(@ID, s.ID)
        AND d.FirstName = COALESCE(@firstname, d.FirstName) OR d.FirstName = 'NONE'
        AND d.LastName = COALESCE(@lastname, d.LastName) OR d.LastName = 'NONE'
        AND d.Street = COALESCE(@street, d.Street)
        AND d.CompanyName = COALESCE(@companyname, d.CompanyName) OR d.CompanyName = 'NONE'
        AND d.HouseNumber = COALESCE(@housenumber, d.HouseNumber)
        AND c.name = COALESCE(@city, c.name))

    SET @ResultCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @ResultString = 'Lookup successful'
    SET @ResultValue = 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ResultString = 'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @ResultValue = 2
END CATCH
END
GO
```

**Example data:**

Subscriber:

```
ID = 1 | Type_ID = 1 | Detail_ID = 2

ID = 2 | Type_ID = 2 | Detail_ID = 3
```

SubscriberDetail:

```
ID = 1 | FirstName = 'Laurens' | LastName = 'De Neys' | CompanyName = NULL | Street = 'Ergens' | HouseNumber = 2 | City_ID = 1

ID = 2 | FirstName = 'Tim' | LastName = 'Blabla' | CompanyName = NULL | Street = 'Iets' | HouseNumber = 26 | City_ID = 2
```

City:

```
ID = 1 | name = 'Liedekerke' | postalCode = 1770

ID = 1 | name = 'Leuven' | postalCode = 3000
```

Comment: Without parentheses your AND/OR conditions are definitely wrong - I know you said you tried changing that but you haven't posted the changed code. It might still be wrong

Comment: Hey Tim, check my edited answer.  I have a feeling that's going to solve your problem.  You should be able to copy and paste my code over your select statement, and see if that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you need to put your OR conditions in parentheses with your original conditions?

For all of these expressions:

```
AND d.LastName = COALESCE(@lastname, d.LastName) OR d.LastName = 'NONE'
```

Change to

```
AND (d.LastName = COALESCE(@lastname, d.LastName) OR d.LastName = 'NONE')
```

**EDIT**

Well, I can't know what is in your DB, but I have a feeling some of that logic is incorrect.  Try this:

```
SELECT s.ID, COALESCE(d.FirstName,'NONE'), COALESCE(d.LastName,'NONE'), d.Street, COALESCE(d.CompanyName,'NONE'), d.HouseNumber, c.name
    FROM Subscriber s
    INNER JOIN SubscriberDetail d ON d.ID = s.Detail_ID
    INNER JOIN City c ON d.City_ID = c.ID
    WHERE (@id is null or s.ID = @ID)
        AND (@firstname is null or d.FirstName = @firstname)
        AND (@lastname is null or d.LastName = @lastname)
        AND (@street is null or d.Street = @street)
        AND (@companyname is null or d.CompanyName = @companyname)
        AND (@housenumber is null or d.HouseNumber = @housenumber)
        AND (@city is null or c.name = @city)
```

Comment: I've tried that already, but did it again now to make sure. That makes all my above examples return no rows.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `WHERE` statement has its `AND` and `OR` conditions arranged in such a way that they are evaluating incorrectly for what I assume you want them to do. You can fix it by encapsulating your OR statments to account for the correct parts. Example:

```
WHERE (s.ID = COALESCE(@ID, s.ID)
    AND (d.FirstName = COALESCE(@firstname, d.FirstName) OR d.FirstName = 'NONE')
    AND (d.LastName = COALESCE(@lastname, d.LastName) OR d.LastName = 'NONE')
    AND d.Street = COALESCE(@street, d.Street)
    AND (d.CompanyName = COALESCE(@companyname, d.CompanyName) OR d.CompanyName = 'NONE')
    AND d.HouseNumber = COALESCE(@housenumber, d.HouseNumber)
    AND c.name = COALESCE(@city, c.name))
```

EDIT: Looking at the same data, there's an additional problem here. You're trying to check equality on Company name to COALESCE(@companyname, d.companyname), but you have cases where your CompanyName is NULL. When a value is NULL, it's unknown, so SQL won't treat it as being equal, even to itself.

This is one reason I generally prefer, rather than the `COALESCE` syntax above to do somethng like this:

`AND (@companyname IS NULL OR d.CompanyName = @companyname)`

The above doesn't care if the stored value for company name is null if the parameter is also null (and if the parameter isn't null, your equality still works out).

Comment: I've tried that already, but did it again now to make sure. That makes all my above examples return no rows.

Comment: Can you add example rows for your three tables into your question so we can get a better look at what you're dealing with?

Comment: @TimD'hoe I've edited my answer to reflect your sample data, although looks like Sonic got there first. :)

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answer, it does give me some more insight.